# Is it possible to generate a single header file from proto file?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have created a config class using Google's `Protobuf` and generated the corresponding `config.h` and `config.cc` files. Now obviously, I have included the resulting header to my library and my library builds just fine.

However, the issue is whenever I use my lib in another project, I need to add the `config.cc` to that project as well and this is cumbersome. Is there a way that I can generate a single header file and then include that header in my library and call it a day? Is there any better way to get around this issue?

### Update

I concatenated the files, but now I'm getting redefinition errors :

```cpp
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2011   'FVConfig::Config_FAN_MODELS_WEIGHTSDefaultTypeInternal': 'class' type redefinition FV  D:\Tervor\Dependencies\include\messages\Config.pb.h 4363    
Error   C2011   'FVConfig::Config_S3FD_MODELS_WEIGHTSDefaultTypeInternal': 'class' type redefinition    FV  D:\Tervor\Dependencies\include\messages\Config.pb.h 4367    
Error   C2011   'FVConfig::Config_DLIB_MODELS_WEIGHTSDefaultTypeInternal': 'class' type redefinition    FV  D:\Tervor\Dependencies\include\messages\Config.pb.h 4371    
Error   C2011   'FVConfig::Config_MTCNN_MODELS_WEIGHTSDefaultTypeInternal': 'class' type redefinition   FV  D:\Tervor\Dependencies\include\messages\Config.pb.h 4375    
...
```

Here is  the whole concatenated file: https://paste.ee/p/IopuI#s=0&l=4338
and the `.cc` content starts from loc 4338.

I think simply concatenating the `.cc` at the end of the header file doesn't do it. Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Just move the implementation to the header?

Comment: I actually hoped for a way that I can use to automate this, so whenever I change the proto definition, the corresponding file gets created automatically and used. this is actually what I have in place now. I can't seem to find a way to do that! so I wonder if I can generate single header from the beginning

Comment: How you would successfully automate this depends on what build sytem you are using. Certainly I've worked on projects where this kind of operation is well automated.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio on Windows and CMake on Linux systems. So something that can be kind of multiplatform. I'm actually writing specific scripts for Linux and windows at the moment to get around this. but I'd appreciate anything that can make it a bit more hassle-free.

Comment: Also, I guess there is no way around generating a single header file out of a proto file. Am I Right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you "need to add the `config.cc` to that project". If you are building a static library, you can add the source file to your library, and have that project link with the library; just like you do with any other source file.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm building a dll (shared lib) thats why I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could build a static library just to house the proto-related sources, and link both the DLL and the project that consumes it with that library. You probably already do that with protobuf runtime (the library where e.g. `protobuf::Message` class is implemented, that `Config` derives from).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. that's a good idea. I'll probably go this route